# Javascript (NodeJS) Callback Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

How do you access parent scope from a callback. The callback is function (err, obj). The var to_user_id is the same in all iterations. It looks like the callbacks are processed after all the iterations are done so the var to_user_id is only one value for all callbacks.

```
for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {

  to_user_id = keys[i].replace('m', '')

  client.get(keys[i], function (err, obj) {
    //var not updating, why is both to_user_id=77
    console.log("match: to_user_id=" + to_user_id + " from_user_id=" + obj)
    var match = "match: to_user_id=" + to_user_id + " from_user_id=" + obj
    io.emit(1, match);
  });

}
```

Output

See how to_user_id is 77 for both iterations. One should be 6 and the last should be 77.

match: to_user_id=77 from_user_id=77

match: to_user_id=77 from_user_id=6

client.get is a redis function just in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `client.get()` calls are asynchronous. As such, the for-loop finishes before any of the `client.get()` callbacks are executed. That means that `to_user_id` will be set to `keys[keys.length - 1].replace('m', '')` by the time the first `client.get()` callback is executed. So that is the reason why you are seeing the same `to_user_id` in your output.

The fix here is to use a closure to capture the current value of `to_user_id`. The simplest way of doing this is to use `keys.forEach()`:

```
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  to_user_id = key.replace('m', '')

  client.get(key, function (err, obj) {
    console.log("match: to_user_id=" + to_user_id + " from_user_id=" + obj)
    var match = "match: to_user_id=" + to_user_id + " from_user_id=" + obj
    io.emit(1, match);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ahh. The closure is created inside the forEach.

Comment: I ended up using your code because I couldn't resist how succinct it was. Javascript is almost as beautiful as Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You must to create closure to save value of `i` variable.

```
for (var i = 0, len = 5; i < len; i++) {
  (function(i, to_user_id) {
    client.get(i, function(err, obj) {
      io.emit("match: to_user_id=" + to_user_id + " from_user_id=" + obj)
    });
  }(i, keys[i].replace('m', '')));
}
```

Comment: Awesome. You're a JS genius.